# Как отключить исключение при генерировании NaN в Си (С89)

Tags: c, delphi, visual-studio

Столкнулся с библиотекой на Си (`proj4`), которая при инициализации себя генерирует `NaN`:

`NaN = sqrt(-1.0);` (см. [geodesic.c](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/blob/master/src/geodesic.c#L88))

Я использую эту библиотеку из Delphi и там от такого финта вываливается исключение *"Floating point invalid operation"*.

С этим исключением, в принципе, бороться можно, но способ не потокобезопасный (внутри системных библиотек Delphi используется глобальная переменная `Default8087CW`):

```
  var  
    VMask: TArithmeticExceptionMask;
  begin        
    VMask := GetExceptionMask();        
    SetExceptionMask(VMask + [exInvalidOp]);
    try 
      // вызов функции, которая бросает исключение
    finally
      SetExceptionMask(VMask);
    end;
  end;
```

Эту библиотеку (`proj.dll`) я собирал сам из сорцов, в MSVC 2008, и возможно указал не правильно какие-то флаги при компиляции, которые влияют на проброс этого исключения?

Подскажите, сталкивался ли кто с такой ситуацией и как с ней можно нормально бороться в многопоточном приложении.

Comment: А почему не заключить в `Try.. Except` и отлавливать именно этот тип исключения? Вот вам и потокобезопасность.

Comment: @kami Если возникает исключение в коде, то его выполнение прерывается и библиотека не до конца выполнит все свои инициализации. Поэтому нужно именно отключить генерирование исключения, чтобы весь код в библиотеке отработал до конца.

Comment: Так если прервался код непосредственно внутри dll на `c`, то каким образом вам поможет игнорирование исключения уже в `Delphi`, *снаружи* прерванного кода? Инициализацию-то уже не восстановишь... В этом случае я не понимаю смысла приведенного вами кода в вопросе.

Comment: @kami так код в `dll` не прерывается. Это не игнорирование, а отключение исключения, которое выполняется через регистры процессора, а не просто в `Delphi`.

Comment: Ага, увидел. Спасибо, не знал про такую возможность.